# How do I install current versions of OpenSSH and LibreSSL?

Tags: software-installation, security, encryption

The versions of OpenSSH and OpenSSL that ship with the Ubuntu base version can be several releases out of date. How can I install updated versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to install current versions of each on your computer.

**First, download, build and install the latest version of LibreSSL**

`cd /usr/local/src` (or whatever directory you like to build software in)

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential checkinstall

curl http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/LibreSSL/libressl-<version-number>.tar.gz | tar -xzv; cd libressl-<version-number>

./configure --libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu; make check; sudo checkinstall
```

**Then build OpenSSH against the updated LibreSSL libraries**

```
curl https://mirror.planetunix.net/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-<version-number>p1.tar.gz | tar -xzv

cd openssh-<version-number>; ./configure --libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-ssl-dir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --without-zlib


make; sudo checkinstall
```

Be aware that your openssh binaries will be downgraded anytime there is an 'update' to the Ubuntu openssh package, and you'll have to re-install.

Comment: To workaround integration problem I'm thinking about creation of snap-package with original OpenSSH/LibreSSL...